# Вычеслить самую длинную убывающую последовательность в списке

Tags: python

Изучаю python вторую неделю . Столкнулся с проблемой что нужно найти такую вот последовательность (например список [41, 15, 9, 62, 23] нужно что-бы вывело [41, 15, 9]).  Ну для начала нужно создать список из которого и будет искаться последовательность.

```
import random
spysok = random.sample(range(1, 100), 20)
```

дальше нужно создать что-то на подобии списка который и будет самой длинной последовательностию
`largest = []`
Дальше нужно сделать цикл который как-бы будет сравнивать элемент а1 и а2, если а а2 меньше а 1, то нужно скорее всего в новый список например `now = [0]`  добавить это и продолжить сравнивать уже а2 и а3 и тд. если а1 например будет меньше а2, то оборвать и начинать перебирать пока следующий элемент не будет меньше пердыдущего. И вот вся проблема в том что не до конца понимаю как это реализовать

Comment: очень сумбурно написано, лично я понял только про 2 недели, вы могли бы точно сформулировать задачу, которую пытаетесь решить, потому что из первого предложения можно понять только, что вам надо `arr[:3]`, а читаешь дальше и понимаешь, что вам что-то другое надо

Comment: Я вот тоже не понял что нужно @A4eVsmisle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это далеко не самое быстрое решение, так как тут я бестолково добавляю элементы в список и проверяю длину. Можно работать только с индексами элементов, если нужна скорость.

```
import random
a = random.sample(range(1, 100), 20)
print(a)
temp = []
result = []
for i in range(0, len(a) - 1):
    if a[i + 1] < a[i] and len(temp) == 0:
         temp.append(a[i])
         temp.append(a[i + 1])
    elif a[i + 1] < a[i] and len(temp) != 0:
         temp.append(a[i + 1])
    else:
         if len(result) < len(temp):
              result = temp
              temp = []
         else:
              temp = []
if len(result) < len(temp):
    print(temp)
elif len(result) == 0 and len(temp) == 0:
    print([a[0]])
else:
    print(result)
```

Comment: У меня вопрос, как вы поняли вопрос человека?
Ему нужно найти как бы серию чисел (как серия побед) но по убыванию?

Comment: Я как понял, так и ответил) А вообще заголовок "Вычеслить самую длинную убывающую последовательность в списке" Ну вроде очевидно. Да и пример есть.

Comment: Да, но сам текст вопроса - заслуживает "похвалы";)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, кланяюсь в ноги так сказать! Нужно будет изучить индексы пока всё делал без них 

Comment: Как ты мог делать без них.)) Я имел ввиду, не добавлять элементы и потом проверять длину, а просто работать с номерами элементов и сравнивать разницу между ними. А в конце взять срез.

Comment: Есть ошибка: выводит `[10]` на `[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

Comment: Да, точно. Исправил

Comment: Оперативно. Правильное ли поведение если на `[1, 2, 3]` выдается `[1]`?

Comment: Извените, нашел еще, `[10, 9, 8, 7, 60, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`  выдает `[10, 9, 8, 7]`

Comment: Исправлено. Еще замечания?)

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант. Сначала создаем список из индексов списка чисел, индексы берутся для тех элементов которые нарушают убывающую последовательность(с них же начинается последовательность) и вычисляем длину от одного такого элемента до другого. Также в этот список добавляются 0 и последний индекс равный длине списка чисел - они являются вспомогательными. Затем вычисляем длину от одного индекса до другого, таким образом находим максимальную убывающую последовательность.

```py
import random

def get_desc_seq(a):
    b = [i for i,x in enumerate(a) if a[i-1] < x]
    b.append(len(a))
    b.insert(0,0)
    b = max((x-b[i-1],x) for i,x in enumerate(b))
    return a[b[1]-b[0]:b[1]] if b[0] > 1 else []
        
a = random.sample(range(1, 100), 20)
print(a)
print(get_desc_seq(a))
```

Comment: Видел этот код на англоязычном overflow но не разобрался и решил что-то самому накидывать

Comment: @A4eVsmisle, я не копировал - сам написал. Добавил немного описания, может поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Вот человек тут получше сделал. Но я же не зря наклепал)
Держите мой код)

```
spysok=[32,1,31,312,13,31,342,52,12,4,144,41,40]

def largest(spysok):
largests = [] #список всех убывающих последовательностей
is_first=True #проверяет первые ли аргумент, дабы узнать добавлять сразу два элемента, или только последний(
              # т.к. первый уже был бы добавлен)
id_of_list=0 #айди нынешнего убывающего листа, чтобы узнать куда добавлять
for i in range(len(spysok)-1):
    if spysok[i]>spysok[i+1]:
        if is_first:
            is_first=False
            largests.append([spysok[i],spysok[i+1]])
        else:
            largests[id_of_list].append(spysok[i+1])
    else:
        if not is_first: #изменяем его айди, только если было добавлено хоть что-то, иначе будет за границей
            id_of_list+=1
        is_first=True #изменяем обратно, чтобы сделать проверку будем добавлять сразу два элемента, или один
return largests
longest_len=0
longest_list=0
for i in largest(spysok):
    if len(i)>longest_len:
        longest_len=len(i)
        longest_list=i
print(longest_list)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я вот примерно также старался делать, но вот растерялся когда дело дошло до того что-бы сравнивать элементы, нужно решить пару таких задач, руку набить так сказать